# Input values into a vector until the end of input?

Tags: c++, input, vector

So I want the user to input something like this:

```
0 15 72 34 92 8
```

and I want to fill a vector of integers with these numbers.

Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> V;
    cout << "Please enter the numbers separated by \n";
    cout << "spaces, then press the \"Enter\" key.\n\n";

    int temp;
    while (cin >> temp)
    {
        V.push_back(temp);
    }
// The programs gets to this point and continuously asks for input



// Print the vector
    cout << "The vector contains [ ";
    for(int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++)
        cout << V.at(i) << " ";
    cout << "], ";

}
```

Comment: You're going to have to decide how the user tells the program they have finished giving input.

Comment: Judging by your user prompt description, it appears you should read the line into a `std::string` first via `std::getline`, then extract it into `int` values via `std::istringstream`

Comment: The `>>` in your while loop returns a reference to `cin` which will never evaluate to false, which is why your loop runs forever.

Comment: How would I rewrite the code so that the loop does not run forever?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code based on this example. It takes input from user until user enters -1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;    

int main()
{
    int number;
    vector<int> userInput;

     do
     {
        cout << "Enter a number (-1 to quit): ";
        cin >> number;

        userInput.push_back(number);

     } while (number != -1);

    for (vector < int >::iterator it = userInput.begin(); it < userInput.end() - 1; it++)
    {
        cout << endl << *it;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, read the entire line as a string using getline and after that fetch every integer and push it into the integer array.

```
vector<int> v;
string buffer;
int data;
getline(cin, buffer);
istringstream iss(buffer);
while (iss >> data)
    v.push_back(data);
```

Comment: Please better describe your problem in your post.