# Unexpected value while placeing integers into an array

Tags: c++

I am trying to fill an array with different integers, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i=0;
    int num;
    int MyArray[]={};
    
    
    while (true) {
        cout<<"sayi giriniz"<<endl;
        cin>>num;
        MyArray[i]=num;
        i++;
        
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
            cout<<MyArray[j]<<endl;
        }
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhCsE.jpg

When I enter the 3rd value it gives an unexpected result.

Comment: This declaration int MyArray[]={}; is invalid and does not make a sense. The number of elements in the array is unspecified.

Comment: Even if `int MyArray[]={};` was valid arrays are a fixed size at compile time and will never grow. Use a `std::vector<int>` instead. Your code should be more like this example: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312047/input-values-into-a-vector-until-the-end-of-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312047/input-values-into-a-vector-until-the-end-of-input)

Answer (score 5):

```cpp
int MyArray[]={};
```

Now, `MyArray` has a size of `0`, so any indexes that you tried to access `MyArray` will cause undefined behavior.

If you want to make an array that is dynamically in size, use `std::vector` in the `<vector>` header.

Change

```cpp
int MyArray[]={};
```

to

```cpp
std::vector<int> MyArray;
```

This:

```
MyArray[i]=num;
i++;
```

To this:

```cpp
MyArray.push_back(num); // you don't even need i
```

This

```
for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
    cout<<MyArray[j]<<endl;
}
```

To this:

```cpp
for(const auto &i : MyArray) // range based for loop, recommend
{
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Also, `using namespace std;` is [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), so don't use it.

Comment: Zero-sized arrays are ill-formed, so OP's code is illegal even without out-of-bounds access.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take input and are unsure about the number of elements, you should use a vector. The array which you have made is of 0 size. It will surely give you an error.